# Undefined array key but query string is correct?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, xmlhttprequest, undefined

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to process form submissions. It has been working perfectly and still does for every other form submission than the one I'm trying to change.

In the request I have a switch block:

```
case "submit_change_username":
    requestURL = "../php/process_change_username.php?";
break;
case "mark_notification_as_read":
    requestURL = "../php/query_notifications.php?notification_action=";
    parameters += encodeURIComponent("mark_notification_as_read") + "&";
    getCurrentElementValue = true;
break;
case "delete_notification":
    requestURL = "../php/query_notifications.php?notification_action=";
    parameters += encodeURIComponent("delete_notification") + "&";
    getCurrentElementValue = true;
break;
```

The first case works fine. It's triggered by a form submission.

The last two cases are triggered by clicking on different divs. I've tried to bake-in the notification_action parameter before my script continues to drag in form element values to append to the `parameters` variable...

```
    if (!directRequest) {
        let fields = getCurrentElementValue ? $(fieldSource) : $(fieldSource).parent().find("select, input, textarea");
        fields.each(function(index, element) {
            if (index != 0) {
                parameters += "&"
            }

            let valueToUse = encodeURIComponent(element.value);

            if ((element.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value == "suspend_user" && !element.checked) || (element.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value == "suspension_reason" && element.value.length == 0)) {
                valueToUse = "";
            }

            parameters += element.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value + "=" + valueToUse;
        });
    }
```

So, all in all, when a user clicks on either div, I'm grabbing an ID from a hidden input tag (e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="notification_id" value="7">`), baking in a notification_action parameter and making the request.

I've checked the full URL including parameters with console.log before the request is sent and it's: `../php/query_notifications.php?notification_action=mark_notification_as_read&notification_id=7`

All seems great, except when trying to access notification_action in PHP...

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    session_start();
    $action = $_POST["notification_action"];
    $notificationID = $_POST["notification_id"];
```

...I get Undefined array key "notification_action".

It does however, pass through notification_id.

Why on Earth would it not receive notification_action??

thanks

In case it's needed, the rest of the script for the request is:

```
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, requestURL);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// debug
    console.log(requestURL + parameters);
    request.send(parameters);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (action != "submit_log_in") {
                $("#modal_cover").css("display", "none");
            }

            $(".lds-spinner").remove();
            $("#php_response").remove();

// debug
            alert(request.responseText);

            if (/\|/.test(request.responseText)) {
                let responseArray = request.responseText.split("|");
                if (/^suspended$/.test(responseArray[0])) {
                    $("#suspend_user").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#suspension_reason").val(responseArray[1]);
                } else {
                    $("#suspend_user").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#suspension_reason").val("");
                }
            } else if (/php_response/.test(request.responseText)) {
                $(fieldSource).after(request.responseText);
            }
        } else {
            if ($(".lds-spinner").length == 0) {
                $("#modal_cover").css("display", "flex").append(spinner);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: When you make a POST request, the parameters at the server are read from the body of the request, not from the URL. You've to pass the data in the argument of `request.send()`. Currently `parameters` seems to contain the values only, not the keys, in the `swicth` you should have: `parameter s+= "notification_action=" + encodeURIComponent("mark_notification_as_read") + "&";`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Teemu!

> ```
>             requestURL = "../php/query_notifications.php?";
>             parameters += "notification_action=" + encodeURIComponent("mark_notification_as_read") + "&";
> ```

woot